# TextInputLayout border gets chopped when it gets refocused and has text

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have started to introduce material design on an existing project. I have a TextInputLayout, however, when it gets refocused and it has text, the border gets chopped. See image

[image]

Any ideas what attribute should be changed on either TextInputLayout or Edittext? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your cursor ballon (bottom) color is white due to which it looks like border cutout so you can either change the color or remove the ballon.

Below attribute can be modified:

```
<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/...</item>
```

Regarding the `primaryColor` attribute, you can change the `primaryColor` of your app here:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Comment: I seem to have seen an attribute where the colorPrimary is white, and setting a different color on colorPrimary for a different style doesn't seem to override it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jeongbebs just try to override ONLY the cursor color using the above snippet I mentioned. It should work.

Comment: @Jeongbebs regarding the primaryColor attribute, you can try to change the primaryColor of your app like below:

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">         <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

Comment: I saw the global theme and it is being set as white. Overriding color primary for a new style works, thanks

Comment: I will add the above snippet in answer as well to help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the cursor marker (don't know the correct name for that thing) is white in your case. I think this color is the accentColor of your app per default.

As documented here https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#outlined-text-field the default color is ?attr/primaryColor

[image]